# Php: Change language in date/strftime/strtotime

Tags: php, date, strtotime, strftime, setlocale

I'm trying to get the output on my second piece of code to be Dutch.
The first code gives the right output, but in English. I tried to get it in Dutch but usually i ended up with 01-01-1970, 12-12-2015 or nothing.
The code should give next friday this week, unless its past monday, then it's fridat next week.

My working code but in English.

```
<?php
$d = strtotime('today');

switch ($d) {
    case strtotime('monday'):
    case strtotime('friday'):
    case strtotime('saturday'):
    case strtotime('sunday'):
        $ff = strtotime('next friday');
        $ffn = date('l d M', $ff);
        echo $ffn;
    break;
    case strtotime('tuesday'):
    case strtotime('wednesday'):
    case strtotime('thursday'):
        $ff = strtotime('next friday' . '+ 7days');
        $fft = date('l d M', $ff);
        echo $fft;
    break;
    default:
        echo "Something went wrong";
}
?>
```

My code which gives a Dutch output, but the wrong date (it gives today's date, not next friday/friday next week.)

By the way, this is my first question ive asked here, so I might be a bit vague or something ;)

Comment: transform your dutch dates into english and then use php's strtotime functions to get the next friday and then convert this back to dutch, maybe php has a localised date i;'m not sure, but you can easily make one just by replacing the days/months strings from/to dutch to/from english

Comment: You can use strftime() to output dates in any language http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php Why you do not return the correct timestamp in your switch statement and then use it with strftime() to display the date in Dutch?

Comment: @YasenZhelev I already used that, but somehow i screwed up my output ( but the language did change ye ). But thanks for the response (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just output the date using strftime() and set_locale() functions. No need to change your code logic if it is correct.

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

```
<?php
$d = strtotime('today');

$format = '%A %d %b';
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'NL_nl');    
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');

switch ($d) {
    case strtotime('monday'):
    case strtotime('friday'):
    case strtotime('saturday'):
    case strtotime('sunday'):
        $ff = strtotime('next friday');
        $ffn = strftime($format, $ff);
        echo $ffn;
    break;
    case strtotime('tuesday'):
    case strtotime('wednesday'):
    case strtotime('thursday'):
        $ff = strtotime('next friday' . '+ 7days');
        $fft = strftime($format, $ff);
        echo $fft;
    break;
    default:
        echo "Something went wrong";
}
?>
```

Comment: i'm trying to show date in french in my laravel blade view this is my code "<?php 
                                 setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');
                                 echo strftime("%d %B %G", strtotime($lastNews->created_at));
                                       ?>  but it is still displayed in english

Answer (score 3):

I used str_replace instead now. It was (for me) an easy and fast way to get the output i needed. But I've only been programming for nearly a year now, so probably my way of fixing it was not the best one. But it works for now (:
Thanks to eveyone who Replied to the thread!

This is what i got now using str_replace.

```
<?php
$d = strtotime('today');
setlocale (LC_TIME,'NL_nl');
ini_set('intl.default_locale', 'nl_NL');
switch ($d) {
    case strtotime('monday'):
    case strtotime('friday'):
    case strtotime('saturday'):
    case strtotime('sunday'):
        $ff = strtotime('next friday');
        $ffn = date('l d F ', $ff);
        $dutch = str_replace (
            array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'Friday'),
            array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mrt', 'Apr', 'Mei', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Vrijdag'),
            $ffn);
        echo $dutch;
    break;
    case strtotime('tuesday'):
    case strtotime('wednesday'):
    case strtotime('thursday'):
        $ff = strtotime('next friday' . '+ 7days');
        $fft = date('l d F', $ff);
        $dutch = str_replace (
            array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'Friday'),
            array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mrt', 'Apr', 'Mei', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Vrijdag'),
            $fft);
        echo $dutch;
    break;
    default:
        echo "Something went wrong";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`strftime()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) is the only PHP date & time function that supports localization.

Both [`date()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`strtotime()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) use only English.

In order to have help [`strftime()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) helps you, you need to use [`setlocale()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) first.

Unfortunately, the second argument of [`setlocale()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) is not standardized, its value depends up to some extent on the operation system where the PHP code runs.

On Unix-like systems (Linux, OSX), use:

```
/* Set locale to Dutch */
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'nl_NL');

/* Output: woensdag  3 juni 2015 */
echo strftime("%A %e %B %Y", strtotime('2015-06-03'));
```

On Windows, use:

```
/* Set locale to Dutch */
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'nld_nld');
```

The above code snippets are copied from the documentation of `setlocale()`. I changed the date and tested the first example (on Mac OSX) but I don't have a Windows system at hand to check if the second one works as advertised. Anyway, I can tell from past experience that the string you need to use on Windows is different than you use on Unix-like systems. If you need to run the code on Windows you can find useful links at the end of the [documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But the problem i got with this method was that my code didnt give the right date output. But i understand that normally this way works without screwing up the outcome. str_replace worked for me without messing with my outcome (so far) So i think that I'll keep using str_replace. But atleast i know now how strftime() etc works (: thnx